# SVN Checkout As Error

Tags: eclipse, svn

I installed both *m2e.subversive* and Subclipse onto eclipse, but when I tried to paste in an svn URL it gives me the error below. I've looked around the net but can't seem to find a solution.

> SVN: 'Checkout As' operation finished with error
>   Selected resource is not cCheckhecked out.
>   Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.
>   If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors update site.
>   If connectors already installed then you can change the selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already installed a connector, this sounds like [Eclipse bug 518033](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518033). See [comment 7](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518033#c7) for a workaround.